# How to extract data from Odoo and display reports in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: odoo, sharepoint-2013

I got an interesting yet confused task. There is an odoo timesheet project developed in Python and we need to extract the timesheet data with the help of Sharepoint. Is there any way to extract the data from Odoo software and display those reports in SharePoint 2013?
If yes how? Please help.

Comment: You have to be more specific, which data from which tables you want to extract and how do you want them to be displayed on sharepoint ? FYI there is always a way.

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas - I edited my question. Actually it is an timesheet Odoo project. We have to extract this data using Sharepoint. I think we  need some APIs.